# jQuery - Creating multiple instance

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload

I'm using the following jquery plugin to file upload.

http://www.jscripts.info/mfupload.php

This works great for a single upload box. I tried for multiple upload boxes by changing the ID into class, but no luck.

This is how its initialize the function,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //function AjaxUpload($posturl,fieldname,formname){
        var errors="";
        //alert($("div.uploadaction").html());
        $('#upload').mfupload({

            type        : '',   //all types
            maxsize     : 20,
            post_upload : $("div.uploadaction").html(),
            folder      : "./",
            ini_text    : "<div class='halfmargin'></div><span>Click / Drag your logo file here</span>",
            over_text   : "<div class='halfmargin'></div><span class='drop'>Drop Here</span>",
            over_col    : 'white',
            over_bkcol  : 'green',

            init        : function(){       
                $("#uploaded").empty();
            },

            start       : function(result){     
                $("#uploaded").append("<div id='FILE"+result.fileno+"' class='files'>"+result.filename+"<div id='PRO"+result.fileno+"' class='progrez_img'><img src='/images/ajax-loader.gif' /></div></div>"); 
            },

            loaded      : function(result){
                $("#PRO"+result.fileno).remove();
                $("#FILE"+result.fileno).html("<div class='smallpadding'>Uploaded: "+result.filename+" ("+result.size+")<input type='hidden' name='hdnfilename[]' value='"+result.filename+"' /></div>");   
                //$('#'+formname).append('<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"hdnfilename[]\" value=\"' +result.filename+ '\">');     

/*              <input type='hidden' name='hdnfilename[]' value='"+result.filename+"' />    
*/          },

            progress    : function(result){
                $("#PRO"+result.fileno).css("width", result.perc+"%");
            },

            error       : function(error){
                errors += error.filename+": "+error.err_des+"\n";
            },

            completed   : function(){
                if (errors != "") {
                    alert(errors);
                    errors = "";
                }
            }
        });

    })
```

Please help me create multiple upload boxes.

Regards.

Comment: it's possible with jquery file upload plugin

Comment: Is that support for Drag and Drop as well, if so please give me a link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

if that plugin allows for multiple instance do

```
$(".upload").each(function(i,e) {

        $("#"+e.id).mfupload({//..
              });

      });
```

or try a better(imo)/more flexible plugin : http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

(start by practising the basic plugin setup before using the provided ui/templating options)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class to apply the plugin to several elements, but the code uses the id of the element, so each element still has to have an id also.